# How to Get The Counts of Redis Values for A Set in Python

Tags: python, redis

I want to get the count of values given the key schema.
I have a set in my Redis with their keys being: 'sample:key:schema'

I want to get total number of values associated with this key.

Currently, I do the following and it works

```
import redis

redis_client = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
key_schema = 'sample:key:schema'
count_of_values = len(redis_client.smembers(key_schema))
```

Is there a better way to get the counts directly without having to fetch all the records and count them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to get with `smembers` and `len` later. You may use `scard` for this, this is the link for python [documentation](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#redis.Redis.scard).

This is from the official redis [documentation](https://redis.io/commands/scard)

> Returns the set cardinality (number of elements) of the set stored at key.